# How to cut a WPF donought in half?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a ring or donought created here:

[How to create a circle with a hole in a circle in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786064/how-to-create-a-circle-with-a-hole-in-a-circle-in-wpf)

I'd now like to have only a half-donought (using circle not path cause I need to resize easily), how to do so in XAML and if possible programmatically.

Comment: Can't you set the `Stretch` property on the Path? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.stretch.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is using path but maybe you will find it useful:

```
<Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill" Height="231" Width="434">
        <Path.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF2F00" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF63B224" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
<Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
        <PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,200">
                <PathFigure.Segments>
                    <LineSegment Point="0,200" />
                    <ArcSegment Size="150,150"
                                SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                Point="400,200" />
                    <LineSegment Point="390,200" />
                    <ArcSegment Size="140,140"
                                SweepDirection="CounterClockwise"
                                Point="10,200" />
                </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry.Figures>
    </PathGeometry>
</Path.Data>
```

There is also pragmatic way check out this [The Mathematics of ArcSegment](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html)

Comment: Since you have `Stretch="Fill"` I don't think there's anything wrong with this.

Comment: I tried seems exactly what I want even if it's Path. In fact Path is OK but need to see how I will resize it. So thanks very much I'll never be able to do that by myself :)