# Click through a transparent image in WPF or Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, transparency

I need to develop a program that consist of an image (png) with an hole in the center. Under this image there will be a frame and I want that clicking on the transparent hole of the image I can click a button inside the frame. I don't know if there is a method to propagate the click through the image or something else.
Thanks for your help

Comment: without knowing sizes of anything: place the image behind the frame/button - zindex

Comment: ...but  I want to maintain the image over the frame.

Comment: is the frame larger than the image? - i mean, what about keeping the frame as small as the hole in the image and then keeping the image on bottom - i don't think there is any easy way of clicking through "transparency" in an image as this is still part of the image. Unless you draw the image live and not use a png. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786064/how-to-create-a-circle-with-a-hole-in-a-circle-in-wpf

Comment: Actually this might answer your question completely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786064/how-to-create-a-circle-with-a-hole-in-a-circle-in-wpf

Comment: unless your not using a circle (which i somehow asumed you were, sorry)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mut set [IsHitTestVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false on the image, then clicks go through.